# swift protocol Equatable: Exposing nonvalue aspects of Equatable types other than class identity is discouraged

Tags: swift, protocols, equals, equatable

I'm currently studying swift API on protocol `Equatable`, and have encountered the following phrase

> Exposing nonvalue aspects of Equatable types other than class
>   identity is discouraged

Could someone explain it to me what is really means?